# Unable to open Android app bundled and uploaded to Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, google-play-console

I've seen a number of other questions about something like this but none of them seem to be exactly what i'm experiencing.

We developed a client application using react native. The application builds and deploys fine for iOS. For android I build a release bundle (`.aab`) file using `./gradlew bundleRelease` command. The bundle builds fine and is accepted as an upload to the Google Play store.

I'm getting reports from some users that they install the app and when clicking the app icon it pops a toast on screen that says 'App not installed'. The weird part is if you long press on the app icon and click Open in the context menu, the app opens fine!!

Can't figure this out for the life of me. Does anyone know why this happens?

### Confirmed Error on Device

Galaxy Note 9 running Android 10

### Build Details

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0" // default: "21.1.0"

        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 31        // version of compile sdk used for project
                //buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'    // version of build tool used for project
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` Include:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.lincolnapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="myappscheme" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      
      <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                  android:value="true"/>
      <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                  android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
              <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

      <service
          android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
          android:exported="false" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I've added the manifest and am reviewing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was the LAUNCHER activity was not being exported.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="false">
```

`android:exported` should be `true`